# updating jlabel onclick of jbutton with methods from another class in java

Tags: java, class, math

I have a class called `driver` in this class I have a gui which has a `jbutton` and a `jlabel`

Onclick of the `jbutton` I am updating the `jlabel` with random math problems.

when the program starts,

```
Jlabel = "Welcome Students"
Jbutton = "Start!"
```

onclick

```
jlabel = "a math problem here"
Jbutton = "Click For Answer"
```

next onclick

```
jlabel = "Answer for the math problem"
jbutton = "Next question"
```

At this point the jlabel and jbutton would be in a loop 
alternating

```
jlabel = alternate math problem and answer
jbutton Click For Answer and Next Question
```

As of now i cant figure out how to add the second onclick function and when the math problem 
appears in the jlabel this is what appears, MathProblems@49bcf06 or some random digits and letters always following MathProblems.

Here is my code,

Driver Class

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Driver extends MathProblems {

    MathProblems question = new MathProblems();
    MathProblems expected = new MathProblems();

    String s = "Welcome Students!";
    String b = "Start!";
    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JButton b1 = new JButton(b);

    JLabel jl = new JLabel(s);

    int i;

    public Driver () {      
        gui();  

    }

    public void gui() { 
        f = new JFrame("Flash Card Program");       
        p = new JPanel();   
        f.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, 1 ) );
        f.add(jl);
        f.add(p);
        p.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, 1 ) );
        p.add(b1);

        jl.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        // pack the frame for better cross platform support
        f.pack();
        // Make it visible
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(560,400); // default size is 0,0
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String b = "Click For Answer";
                b1.setText(b.toString());
                jl.setText(question.toString());

          }
      });

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                String b = "Next Question";
                b1.setText(b.toString());
                jl.setText(expected.toString());

          }
      });
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                new Driver();
                new MathProblems();

           }
        });
    } // End main Method

       } // End class Driver
```

MathProblems Class

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathProblems {
     private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 10;
     private static final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     private static final Random random = new Random();

     public void run() {
         while(true) {  
             final int a = random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);
             final int b = random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);

             final int type = random.nextInt(4);

             switch (type) {
                case 0: 
                   add(a, b);
                break;
                case 1: 
                   subtract(a, b);
                break;
                case 2:
                   multiply(a, b);
                break;
                case 3:
                    divide(a, b);
                 break;
             }
         }  
     }

     private void add(final int a, final int b) {
         final int expected = a + b;

         final int answer = askQuestion(a + " + " + b + "=");

         checkResult(expected, answer); 
     }

     private void subtract(final int a, final int b) {
         final int expected = a - b;

         final int answer = askQuestion(a + " - " + b + "=");

         checkResult(expected, answer); 
     }

     private void multiply(final int a, final int b) {
         final int expected = a * b;

         final int answer = askQuestion(a + " * " + b + "=");

         checkResult(expected, answer); 
     }

     private void divide(final int a, final int b) {
         final int expected = a / b;

         final int answer = askQuestion(a + " / " + b + "=");

         checkResult(expected, answer); 
     }

     private int askQuestion(final String question) {
         System.out.print(question);

         return in.nextInt(); 
     }  

     private void checkResult(final int expected, final int answer) {
         if (expected == answer) {
            System.out.println("Correct answer! You rock!");
         } else {
            System.out.println("WROOONG! You suck!");
         }    
     } 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting `MathProblems@49bcf06` as output is because you are calling `toString()` on `MathProblems` without overriding it. The output you are getting is the *hashcode* of the `MathProblems` object, which is the default behaviour of `toString()`. Inside `MathProblems`, you will have to define this:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
   // return the String you want displayed.
}
```

---

Another issue you have is that when you add the second `ActionListener` to `b1`, it overwrites the first one. I haven't tried running your code, but I think this is going to cause your button to always say "Next Question", and the label will always display the string from `expected` and never from `answer`. You could try something like this:

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(b1.getText().equals("Click For Answer")
            {
                String b = "Next Question";
                b1.setText(b);
                jl.setText(expected.toString());
            }
            else
            {
                String b = "Click For Answer";
                b1.setText(b);
                jl.setText(question.toString());
            }
      }
});
```

Also, you don't need to call `toString()` on `b` because it is already a `String`.

---

## Edits:

Driver class:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Driver extends MathProblems {

    MathProblems problems = new MathProblems();
    private static final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String s = "Welcome Students!";
    String b = "Start!";
    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JButton b1 = new JButton(b);

    JLabel jl = new JLabel(s);

    int i;

    public Driver () {      
        gui();  
    }

    public void gui() { 
        f = new JFrame("Flash Card Program");       
        p = new JPanel();   
        f.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, 1 ) );
        f.add(jl);
        f.add(p);
        p.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, 1 ) );
        p.add(b1);

        jl.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        // pack the frame for better cross platform support
        f.pack();
        // Make it visible
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(560,400); // default size is 0,0
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(b1.getText().equals("Click For Answer")
                {
                    String s = in.nextLine();
                    int answer = Integer.parseInt(s);
                    String result = problems.checkResult(answer);
                    j1.setText(result);
                    String b = "Next Question";
                    b1.setText(b);
                }
                else
                {
                    problems.run();
                    j1.setText(problems.getQuestion());
                    String b = "Click For Answer";
                    b1.setText(b);

                }
          }
});
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                new Driver();
           }
        });
    } // End main Method

} // End class Driver
```

---

Math Problems class:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathProblems {
     private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 10;
     private static final Random random = new Random();

     private int expected = 0;
     private String question = "";

     public void run() {
         final int a = random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);
         final int b = random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER);

         final int type = random.nextInt(4);

         switch (type) {
             case 0: 
                 add(a, b);
                 break;
             case 1: 
                subtract(a, b);
                break;
             case 2:
                multiply(a, b);
                break;
             case 3:
                 divide(a, b);
                 break;
         }
     }

     private void add(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a + b;

         askQuestion(a + " + " + b + "=");
     }

     private void subtract(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a - b;

         askQuestion(a + " - " + b + "=");
     }

     private void multiply(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a * b;

         askQuestion(a + " * " + b + "=");
     }

     private void divide(final int a, final int b) {
         expected = a / b;

         askQuestion(a + " / " + b + "=");
     }

     private int askQuestion(final String question) {
         this.question = question;
     }  

     public String getQuestion() {
         return question;
     }

     public String checkResult(final int answer) {
         if (expected == answer) {
            return "Correct answer! You rock!";
         } else {
            return "WROOONG! You suck!";
         }    
     } 

}
```

Comment: Amazing... you fixed me right up thank you, I just can not for the life of me figure out why the toString wont work. i did this and it keeps giving me error. @Override
 public String toString()
 {
   return askQuestion();
 }

Comment: That is because your `askQuestion()` method returns an `int`, but `toString()` must return a `String`, so `toString()` cannot return the value from `askQuestion()`.

Comment: I am completely lost here. I understand doing Integer.toString but I am not understanding how to implement this. please show me.

Comment: You would call `Integer.toString(askQuestion());`

Comment: The problem is that your `askQuestion()` method expects an argument. I think what you want to do is have `askQuestion()` store the question string in a member variable, and then `toString()` can just return that variable.

Comment: yes it wants an argument.. i was thinking this should work  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return Integer.toString(askQuestion(question or String question??));
  }

Comment: something like this?   private int askQuestion(final String question) {
      String s = question;
      System.out.print(s);

         return in.nextInt(); 
     }  
     
  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return Integer.toString(s);
  }

Comment: I have added some rewritten versions of your classes. Have a look over them and let me know if you have any questions. I haven't tested them so I might have made some errors, but I think you should be able to get the idea.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: asking for return statement here    private int askQuestion(final String question) {
         this.question = question;
     }

Comment: oops, change `private int askQuestion` to `private void askQuestion`

Comment: would private String make sense since it is returning a String?

Comment: `askQuestion` is not returning a String. It is just setting the `question` variable so that it can be retrieved later.

Comment: Ok got ya. This is so confusing to me. I am happy as hell that I have made it this far. We got it working right the only thing left is its not posting the answer when you click the button the second time.

Comment: Where do you want the string to show up that says whether you got it right or not?

Comment: I dont need it to even post that actually. I just want the answer to appear in the jlabel taking the place of the question. then the jbutton saying next question

Comment: In, that case you can just take everything out of the `checkResult()` method and replace it with `return expected;`. You could also get rid of the argument to `checkResult()`

Comment: ok when I change the method to just return expected; i get an error on that line. Can i not just leave it the same and then change the else statement to just return the expected; ????

Comment: Yeah, you could do that. I'll have to correct myself though. It should actually be `return expected.toString();`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50828/discussion-between-nichodiaz-and-gla3dr)